# How do I use "still" in a negative sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I'm having trouble with the use of "still". Which of these is correct?

1. This area **is still not** widespread in Latin America.
2. This area **still is not** widespread in Latin America.
3. This area **is not** widespread in Latin America **still**.

Comment: Hello, Ju C. Haven't you found any example sentences showing usage/s in dictionaries? Variant (1) is most commonly found. (But how can an area be widespread?)

Comment: Hi Edwin! No, I haven't found many examples of negative sentences. In this context,"area" is the area of expertise. Does it sound odd? Thank you for your answer, it's been really helpful

Comment: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/still) **_still_** [A2] examples 2 & 7.

Comment: thanks, I had already visited the CED website. The examples there weren't really helpful though, since they only use contracted forms in negative sentences. Contractions are not an option in this formal letter I'm reviewing and I don't want to alter the author's logic too much

Comment: [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/still) gives: 'still had not made up her mind.' but this shows an emphasising position for 'still'; between the auxiliary and 'not' is the normal position.

Comment: thank you so much!